# What is the hotkey for sculpting grease pencils included in v2.77?

Tags: grease-pencil

What is the hotkey for sculpting grease pencils? Hotkey <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> doesn't work here as described in this [blender wiki page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/GPencil), I can only edit strokes.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you've solved this problem as yet, but the method to sculpt Grease Pencil strokes is as follows:

- press 'Enable Editing' in the Grease Pencil tools panel on the *Toolshelf* or choose *Edit Strokes* interaction mode in the 3D Viewport header;
- choose desired brush (on the *Toolshelf* > *Grease Pencil* *Sculpt Strokes* rollout)
- **press and hold** the <kbd>E</kbd> key whilst pressing the <kbd>LMB</kbd> or using the pen of a tablet.

Ensure you still have the <kbd>RMB</kbd> as your object selection choice. If you've changed the preference for selection to the <kbd>LMB</kbd> then you will need to hold the <kbd>E</kbd> key and use the <kbd>RMB</kbd> to sculpt your Grease Pencil strokes.

Comment: I find that there isn't an 'enable editing' in my 2.78, but if you press Tab to get a pie menu, there is 'edit' there and that brings up the gpancil sculpt. I just found this after thinking I was losing my mind.